# Laravel relation problem after update to version 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-6

i updated laravel version from 5.6 to 6 one week ago for implementing new things on my API, problem is after the update one of my relations just broke.
At certain point after login i need to retrieve some info based on who is connected, on a 3 level relation (cme_permissions.subcomisionData.members) and it brokes on second level (cme_permissions.subcomisionData), i looked at this using dd() step by step.
I'm just starting into this world of programming and i don't know what the heck is happening, thanks for the help.

Query:

```
User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)
      ->with('cme_permissions.subcomisionData.members')->get();
```

First relation (User):

```
    public function cme_permissions() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\CME\CMEPermission');
    }
```

Second relation:

```
class CMEPermission extends Model
{
    public $table = 'cme_permissions';

    public function subcomisionData() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CME\CMESubcomision', 'subcomision');
    }

    function user() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Third relation:

```
class CMESubcomision extends Model
{
  public $table = 'cme_subcomision';
  public $incrementing = false;
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function members() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CME\CMEPermission', 'subcomision')
      ->with('user');
  }

}
```

This still works on my pre-version before the update so i don't know if the problem is with the dependencies in composer.json or what, whatever here it is:
Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "6.0.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.5",
        "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel": "6.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Edit: It doesn't display any error just a null on the second relation

```
      #relations: array:1 [
        "cme_permissions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#469
          #items: array:1 [
            0 => App\CME\CMEPermission {#466
              +table: "cme_permissions"
              #connection: "mysql"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:5 [
                "id" => 2
                "user_id" => 1685
                "email" => "PRU_0004@mail.es"
                "subcomision" => "1.1"
                "cme_role" => "Vocal"
              ]
              #original: array:5 [
                "id" => 2
                "user_id" => 1685
                "email" => "PRU_0004@mail.es"
                "subcomision" => "1.1"
                "cme_role" => "Vocal"
              ]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [
                "subcomisionData" => null
              ]
```

Comment: Please edit and include the error that is showing

Comment: @KhaldounNd i added it, thanks a lot.

Comment: if it doesn't have any error. your defined a wrong relationship. that is why it displays null value @Imzel

Comment: @MohamedRaza but then, the way to make that relations should have change because on my same application with laravel 5.6 it works fine. Do you know if any of this relations have changes with next versions of laravel?